# Is the word, follow, a transitive verb?

Tags: grammar

Is the following sentence grammar correct ? 
"Her acting career officially began in 2002 when she landed her first TV role. Other small parts on TV and in a few films followed."
Does "followed" in the sentence need an object ? 
If no, I thought it should be "Other small parts on TV and in a few films is followed". Is my understanding correct?

Comment: No: this is an example of the transitive verb "follow" being used in an intransitive construction. We would say that the direct object is 'unexpressed'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your understanding is not correct. In your example, the verb 'follow' is used intransitively to mean 'come after in time or order'.

> 2 Come after in time or order.
>
> ‘the six years that followed his restoration’
>
> **no object:** ‘the rates are
>   as follows’

https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/follow